# White blinking when changing background image

Tags: html, css

On my website I have a div with a blurred image, and I want this image to be unblurred on hover, progressively (with `transition-property` and `transition-duration`). I prepared two differents versions of my image, blurred and unblurred. The problem is that, online (even though I have optical fiber) and on my computer, there's a quick white blinking before the transition occurs.
Why is that, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Post your code please. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: @narfi what css code you have added to make your image as blurred, please add your codes.

Comment: You can not animated 1 image to another image. In order animate a blur you have to use the unblurred image and use a CSS property to blur the image and animate that css property on hover

Comment: The blur property in CSS also blurs the text, and doesn't do exactly what I had in mind. Here's what my code looks like :
`.pros {    background-image:url('../img/equipe_2016.png');    display:block;    width:100%;    height:500px;    background-repeat:no-repeat;    -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;    -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;    -ms-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;    -o-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out; } ` and `.pros:hover {    background-image: url('../img/equipe_2016-nb.jpg'); }` with equipe_2016.png being the blurred image, and equipe_2016-nb.jpg not

Comment: @narfi put your code in your question... not in the comments section please. See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties) for a list of CSS properties you can animate. Notice that `background-image` is not one of them. It's impossible to animate 1 static image to another in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use css to blur your image, you could use a pseudo element `:after` to stack your images.

You put the unblurred over the blurred one, with `opacity: 0`, on hover, you change to `opacity:1`

It won't blink this way.

Comment: Could you explain how i would use it here ? I've never used it and I don't see how to in this context

Comment: You can check this fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/y9ywtLau/
I have a ``div``with a ``background``, a pseudo element ``div:after`` with the background blured, and a ``p`` for the text.

Comment: I'm glad I could help ! You can pu this as a valid answer to your question, this way, if someone check your question, he will know that there is a solution.